# Is there a way of having Expertise with the Poisoner's Kit?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, proficiency

Is there any way to attain **Expertise** (i.e. a doubled proficiency bonus) with a **Poisoner's Kit**?

My character is a Rogue, so I have the proficiency already, but I want to have Expertise with this tool if possible.

Comment: Very related on [Can I get expertise in Smith's tools?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116380/is-there-any-means-to-acquire-smiths-tools-expertise-through-leveling-up)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

An [Aereni elf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte/races-of-eberron#ElvesofAerenal) (WGtE, p. 73) chooses one skill or tool to gain double proficiency in at first level.

An [Unearthed Arcana: Races of Eberron](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf) changeling (p. 2) can do similar, gaining double proficiency with a specific tool in a specific persona, as well as the Envoy Warforged (p. 9 ibid.) via a specific integrated tool.

An *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* [changeling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/changeling) (p. 18) cannot, however, nor can the [warforged](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged) (p. 36) in that source.

Comment: Thank you @Pleasestopbeingevil for letting me pick your brains - this is really helpful.

Comment: @NautArch: Originally, WotC never used "expertise" as a mechanical term, just as the name of the bard and rogue features that granted a doubled proficiency bonus in a skill or tool; other instances of doubled proficiency bonus simply referred to the doubled proficiency bonus itself. (The community did often use "expertise" like a mechanical term to refer to any source of doubled proficiency bonus nevertheless.) Then *Xanathar's* treated like it was a mechanical term when it used it in the Prodigy human racial feat and in the *skill empowerment* spell, repeating the definition alongside it.